# Adding a react component as shortcut into a Wordpress site

Tags: php, reactjs, wordpress, elementor

I'm trying to get a React component into a wordpress site as shortcode. I have even added multiple console logs to try to diagnose the issue but no errors pop out.

`<div id="my-react-app"></div>` does appear in the HTML along with `<script>console.log("Shortcode Executed!");</script>` and I'm getting these logs:

```
Shortcode Executed!
DOMContentLoaded event fired...
```

but nothing else, and no component is rendered.

I'm adding it as a shortcode using the elementor shortcode widget, but I don't see how that would affect it.

This is my code:

testimonio-carousel.php

```php
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Testimonio Carousel
Description: A simple WordPress plugin to display a React app as a shortcode.
Version: 1.0
*/

function testimonio_carousel_shortcode() {
   ob_start(); // Start output buffering

   // Include the React app files
   include_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'TestimonioCarousel/index.assets.php');
   // Add any other necessary includes or configurations

   // Output the React app container
   echo '<div id="my-react-app"></div>';

   // Add any other necessary HTML or PHP code

   return ob_get_clean(); // Return the buffered content
}
add_shortcode('testimonio_carousel', 'testimonio_carousel_shortcode');
```

index.js

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  console.log("DOMContentLoaded event fired...");

  const { render } = wp.element;

  // React component
  const MyReactComponent = () => {
      console.log("MyReactComponent is mounting...");

      return React.createElement(
          "div",
          { className: "container" },
          React.createElement(App)
      );
  };

  // Check if the target element exists
  const targetElement = document.getElementById("my-react-app");
  if (targetElement) {
      console.log("Target element exists. Rendering React component...");
      render(React.createElement(MyReactComponent), targetElement);
  } else {
      console.error("Error: Target element not found!");
  }
});
```

App.js

```js
// app.js
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h2>Hello World From React App</h2>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```